# swift long non editable text in textview (i can't see text from the beginning)

Tags: ios, swift, textview, swift2, longtext

I'm trying to insert a long non editable text using `TextView` in Swift. 
No problem with length or vertical scrolling. The problem is that when `UIView` starts I can't see text from the beginning but I always see the final part.

I attached 2 images: how it looks and how it should be.

[image: HOW IT LOOKS]

[image: HOW IT SHOULD BE]

Comment: what does your code looks like?

Comment: No code at this moment for this UI View. I only utilized Xcode drag and drop tools. I could add it if necessary but I wished It could be possible to reach my goal in a faster way.

Comment: IN that case, you seem to be missing a vertical constraint where TextView and the nav bar are aligned.

Comment: Here are my textview constraints: 

    bottom = textview.bottom;
    textview.centerX = centerX;
    textview.top = Top Layout Guide.bottom;
    textview.Leading = leadingMargin + 4

Comment: Just check if there is any constraint ambiguity or misplaced view

Comment: None of those. I found the solution (read below).

Answer (score 1):

Follow the hint posted by Nate Mann, I found the solution.

It's correct:
    myTextview.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0,0))

but you have to put in viewDidAppear:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
     myTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `mytextView..scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))`

put this in `viewDidLoad()`